# How to test a pure-virtual class without implementation?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have the following class:

```
// IVirtualController.hpp
class IVirtualController
{
public:
  virtual InputCode validate(int keycode) = 0;
  virtual ~IVirtualController();
};
```

And now I want to mock this class:

```
// InputManagerTest.cpp
class MockController : public IVirtualController
{
public:
  MOCK_METHOD1(validate,InputCode(int keycode));
};
```

But this doesn't work!
I get the following errors:

> test/input/InputManagerTest.o: In function `MockController::~MockController()':
>   test/input/InputManagerTest.cpp:19: undefined reference to`IVirtualController::~IVirtualController()'
>   test/input/InputManagerTest.cpp:19: undefined reference to `IVirtualController::~IVirtualController()'
>
> test/input/InputManagerTest.o: In function `IVirtualController::IVirtualController()':
>   test/input/../../src/input/IVirtualController.hpp:14: undefined reference to`vtable for IVirtualController'
>
> test/input/InputManagerTest.o: In function `MockController::MockController()':
>   test/input/InputManagerTest.cpp:15: undefined reference to`IVirtualController::~IVirtualController()'
>
> test/input/InputManagerTest.o:(.rodata._ZTI14MockController[_ZTI14MockController]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for IVirtualController'

A search told me that "undefined reference to vtable/typeinfo" errors are caused by a missing implementation, a missing "= 0" behind the virtual method declaration or a non-virtual destructor.
The class IVirtualController isn't implemented, but that shouldn't be a problem since the MockController is implementing it, right? Commenting out the whole InputManagerTest.cpp mock file "solves" the problem, even though IVirtualController is used in an another class.

How do I test it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. A destructor **must always be implemented**. Even a pure virtual one.

That's because of how it works. `virtual` applied to a destructor holds <del>a different</del> more meaning. Usually, a `virtual` method isn't called if it's overriden in a derived class, but a `virtual` destructor will still be called, so an implementation is required.

The `=0` for a destructor only makes the class abstract, but, as stated before, an implementation is still required.

Comment: virtual for dtors doesnt have a different meaning, it is just that dtors implicitly call the dtors of the subobjects.

Comment: @PlasmaHH yeah, I guess it shares some meaning, but also adds some.